# Extracting number from a formatted text file Java

Tags: java, string, file-io, int

I have a text file containing lines of strings followed by two numbers, separated by a colon. For example:

```
...................
words 1:1
morewords 2:1
something 3:1
else 4:2
elsewhere 5:2
....................
middleItem 313 : 60
middleOther 314 : 60
......................
secondToLast 138714 : 29698
last 138715 : 29698
.......................
```

I would like to be able to extract the number on the left and right of the colon and be able to read them as Integers. I need to be able to use those int numbers to perform a calculation later, so reading them as a String would not help.

I have tried using substrings and regex expressions but am not able to figure out a proper means of doing this. Any tips would be helpful!

Comment: the regex for this is pretty simple. show what you tried.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I used sc.findInLine("[0-9]"); But there are sometimes numbers in the string items themselves, leading to wrong assignment of variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(<OUR_FILE>)
sc.nextInt()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("file"); // A delimiter can also be used to separate lines
while (s.hasNext()) {
    if (s.hasNextInt()) { 
        int a = (s.nextInt()); //  found integer
    } else {
        s.next(); // read the next token
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams to create a map, that maps each word to a `Pair<Integer, Integer>`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)$");

Path input = Paths.get("input.txt");
try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(input)) {
    Map<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>> map
        = br.lines() // Get Stream of lines
            .map(String::trim) // Safety trim
            .map(p::matcher) // Get mathcer for each line
            .filter(Matcher::find) // Filter on lines that match
            .collect( // Collect into map
                Collectors.toMap(
                    m -> m.group(1), // The word is the key
                    // Maps to a Pair of the 2 integers
                    m -> new Pair<>(Integer.valueOf(m.group(2)), Integer.valueOf(m.group(3)))
                )
            );

    /* Usage */
    Pair<Integer, Integer> pair = map.get("middleItem");
    System.out.println(pair.getKey()); // 313
    System.out.println(pair.getValue()); // 60
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

As a note: regex is not my speciality, so there might be  better pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way, but what comes first  to my mind is using

```
scanner.nextInt() = variable1, 
scanner.nextInt() = variable2
```

and so on. Then, writing out all of your logic and calculations using the variables you assign.

Doing this (combined with poorvankBhatia's answer) should let you use the entire document.